# " Dependencies installation error" : Is Netlify asking for a previous version of node to deploy the site?

Tags: reactjs, deployment, netlify

While deploying my app with Netlify I am getting this error

`Dependencies installation error`

Is it asking me to install a previous version of node locally and redeploy it?

```
`10:25:19 AM:   Dependencies installation error                               
10:25:19 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
10:25:19 AM: ​
10:25:19 AM:   Error message
10:25:19 AM:   A Netlify Function is using "firebase-functions" but that dependency has not been installed yet.
10:25:19 AM: ​
10:25:19 AM:   By default, dependencies inside a Netlify Function's "package.json" are not automatically installed.
  

There are several ways to fix this problem:
10:25:19 AM:     - Removing your Function's "package.json" and adding the dependencies to the project's top-level "package.json" instead. This is the fastest and safest solution.
10:25:19 AM:     - Running "npm install" or "yarn" inside your Netlify Function in your build command.
10:25:19 AM:     - Adding the following plugin to your "netlify.toml":
10:25:19 AM: ​
10:25:19 AM:   [[plugins]]
10:25:19 AM:   package = "@netlify/plugin-functions-install-core"
10:25:19 AM: ​​
10:25:19 AM:   In file "/opt/build/repo/functions/index.js"
10:25:19 AM:   Cannot find module 'firebase-functions'
10:25:19 AM:   Require stack:
10:25:19 AM:   - /opt/buildhome/.netlify-build-nvm/versions/node/v12.22.6/lib/node_modules/@netlify/build/node_modules/@netlify/zip-it-and-ship-it/src/node_dependencies/resolve.js
10:25:19 AM:   - /opt/buildhome/.netlify-build-nvm/versions/node/v12.22.6/lib/node_modules/@netlify/build/node_modules/@netlify/zip-it-and-ship-it/src/node_dependencies/index.js
10:25:19 AM:   - /opt/buildhome/.netlify-build-nvm/versions/node/v12.22.6/lib/node_modules/@netlify/build/node_modules/@netlify/zip-it-and-ship-it/src/main.js
10:25:19 AM:   - /opt/buildhome/.netlify-build-nvm/versions/node/v12.22.6/lib/node_modules/@netlify/build/src/plugins_core/functions/index.js
10:25:19 AM:   - /opt/buildhome/.netlify-build-nvm/versions/node/v12.22.6/lib/node_modules/@netlify/build/src/commands/get.js
10:25:19 AM:   - /opt/buildhome/.netlify-build-nvm/versions/node/v12.22.6/lib/node_modules/@netlify/build/src/core/main.js
10:25:19 AM:   - /opt/buildhome/.netlify-build-nvm/versions/node/v12.22.6/lib/node_modules/@netlify/build/src/core/bin.js
10:25:19 AM: ​
10:25:19 AM:   Resolved config
10:25:19 AM:   build:
10:25:19 AM:     command: CI= npm run build
10:25:19 AM:     commandOrigin: ui
10:25:19 AM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/build
10:25:19 AM:     publishOrigin: ui
10:25:19 AM:   functionsDirectory: /opt/build/repo/functions
10:25:20 AM: Caching artifacts
10:25:20 AM: Started saving node modules
10:25:20 AM: Finished saving node modules
10:25:20 AM: Started saving build plugins
10:25:20 AM: Finished saving build plugins
10:25:20 AM: Started saving pip cache
10:25:20 AM: Finished saving pip cache
10:25:20 AM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
10:25:20 AM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
10:25:20 AM: Started saving maven dependencies
10:25:20 AM: Finished saving maven dependencies
10:25:20 AM: Started saving boot dependencies
10:25:20 AM: Finished saving boot dependencies
10:25:20 AM: Started saving rust rustup cache
10:25:20 AM: Finished saving rust rustup cache
10:25:20 AM: Started saving go dependencies
10:25:20 AM: Finished saving go dependencies
10:25:23 AM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
10:25:23 AM: Creating deploy upload records
10:25:23 AM: Failing build: Failed to build site
10:25:23 AM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
10:25:23 AM: Finished processing build request in 2m12.906017596s`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the functions directory from the Netlify App.
To do so:

- Go to **Site settings**.
- On your left side scroll till you see **functions** and click
- Then click **Edit settings**. In File directory delete **functions**
  and the click save and retry to deploy.